# LEFT JOIN not returning NULL

Tags: sql, join, null, ms-access-2013

I guess the problem comes down to this: what are some extreme scenarios where using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` **DOES NOT** return the values as expected? Because in the result set I'm expecting the fields I joined on (`item` and `ID`) + any NULL values where the rows don't match, but `item` and `ID` don't show up.

**Info:**

`qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2` returns 95 rows.

`qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2` could have NULL values for `MaxOfMaxOfjob_Date`, `SumOfSumOfqty_on_hand`, `product_code`, and `whse`, *whereas* `ID` and `item` will always have a value.

`qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3` returns 85 rows.

`qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3` does not have any NULL values in any field, but excludes 10 `id` and `item` rows.

**The query:**

```
SELECT 
qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.ID, 
qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.item, 
qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.MaxOfMaxOfjob_date, qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.SumOfSumOfqty_on_hand, qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.product_code, 
qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.whse, 
qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.jobnumber

FROM 
qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2 
LEFT JOIN qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3 ON (qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2.item = qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.item) AND (qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2.ID = qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3.ID);
```

---

Result set using my query + the suggestion in one of the answers to use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJd8h.jpg)

Comment: try to setup a self-contained example on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Minimize, add sample table data, current result and expected result!

Comment: Try reversing query order or use `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Wouldn't the non-matching qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2 rows fail to match  on Query4 ?  - oops no - sorry Misread "Query2" for "MaxDate2"

Comment: You are saying that there is at least one item/id combination for which there is a record in qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2 but not in qry_HersheySAPMaxDate3 and the query shown does not have any result row with NULLs? This doesn't seem possible. Please check again.

Comment: I don't know how else I can "check again". Re-running the query produces the same results (please see the image I've included in the question).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm not saying that it doesn't produce blank rows, but that it produces **entirely** blank rows (see the image). How can this be if I'm joining on `item` and `ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You complain about your query producing entirely blank rows. Let's see why:

You outer join qry3 to qry2. That means when there is no match for a qry2 record in qry3, then a pseudo qry3 record with all columns set to null gets joined.

In your query you select only fields from qry3, so in an outer join case they are all null. Select qry2.ID and qry2.item instead of qry3.ID and qry3.item to see the values that have no match:

```
SELECT 
  qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2.ID, 
  qry_HersheySAPMaxDate2.item,
```

Comment: Oh my goodness....you are absolutely correct....Wow lol. Using the Design View in Access I wouldn't have guessed that it mattered which one I selected from....

Comment: I **SINCERELY** thank you for your patience on this!!! I know it was really frustrating to read and work through all of the info!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use LEFT OUTER JOIN if you want the NULL values to be included in the result

Comment: This doesn't work. Instead of including all items and IDs it simply includes entirely blank rows. http://imgur.com/eglVMcu